# running a php program from command line with a default argument list

Tags: php, shell, command-line, arguments, executable

I want to run my php program from the command line, but I always have to type `php program` instead of just typing `program`. How do I make it known to the shell that whenever I type `program` it runs the program?

Also, I have some arguments that I parse using `getopt()`. I also have a configuration file, which has a `DEFAULT_ARGS=` setting. I want the user to be able to set the default args, and if they run `program` without arguments `DEFAULT_ARGS` takes over and becomes the argument list.

Without writing my own parser, is there a way to "spoof" the `argv[]` variable or somehow make `getopt()` work with the string I've specified in the configuration file instead?

For example, if I wanted to run this on the command line: `php program -a 300 --debug`, instead I will have `DEFAULT_ARGS=-a 300 --debug` in my configuration file and simply write `program` to run the program. This is my end goal.

Answer (score 0):

If your OS os Linux add the sheabang on top of the script

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: set file permissions: chmod 755 yourapp.php

Comment: The execution of the file works fine at the moment, this isn't the problem at all.